# get the exact date of a weekly high (or low) in pine script

Tags: date, time, request, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to get the exact date of a weekly `high` (or low) in trading view's pine script.

Let's imagine we are looking at `Weekly` candles, we do know the `high` and `low` values already, but how to query/get the actual exact date (and optionally time) for the H and L (obviously at a lower `Daily` timeframe -- which can be queries easily with the `request.security*`)?

So far I can't see an obvious way to do it and I have been reading the time-related functions in the ref.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `security()` function for this purpose and you don't need to.

Use the `timeframe.change()` function to figure out if it is a new HTF bar, and then keep track of the high price and its time with `var` variables.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

is_new_week = timeframe.change("W")

var weekly_high_price = high
var weekly_high_time = time
var label weekly_high_label = label.new(na, na, "Weekly\nHigh", xloc=xloc.bar_time, yloc=yloc.abovebar, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white)

if (is_new_week)
    weekly_high_price := high
    weekly_high_time := time
    label.set_xy(weekly_high_label, weekly_high_time, weekly_high_price)
else
    if (high > weekly_high_price)
        weekly_high_price := high
        weekly_high_time := time
        label.set_xy(weekly_high_label, weekly_high_time, weekly_high_price)

plot(weekly_high_price, "Weekly High", color.green)
```

[image]